# Can file paths be replaced by memory resources?

Tags: php, mysql, resources, imagemagick, montage

I'w writing a PHP script that uses Montage, which is an extension of ImageMagick that creates tiled arrays of images. The Montage syntax is straightforward:

```
montage image1.png image2.png image3.png -tile x1 -geometry 50x50 out.png
```

However, I'm generating these images on the fly and I would hate to have to write them to disk just to run this command. Is there some way I can pass there resources in without writing them to file?

(This isn't really a Montage question, but rather a general question that could apply to many different situations.)

Any help would be great!

Comment: You could use a memory-based filesystem like `tmpfs`

Comment: How are you integrating montage with dynamic images and PHP right now?  Is it generate images with PHP and then have PHP make a shell call to montage?

Comment: @FoolishSeth: The images are generated by a custom C script, then I'm using `passthru` to get the raw image data. I've been writing this to files and then using Montage, but I'd like to skip the writing to file part...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: This is the first I'm hearing of tmpfs - sounds very interesting. I would imagine the setup is quite involved?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: After a bit of reading, it sounds like I can just save the files to `/dev/shm` (on Ubuntu), which would in fact save it into RAM. Is that correct? If so, that's the perfect solution!

Comment: It could be elsewhere (perhaps under `/run`) try `df | grep tmpfs` to find out, and you could even make & mount another such filesystem. And the files are stored in "virtual" memory.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yep, it's `/run`. I think this is my answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, you could find some [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) file system (e.g. with `df | grep tmpfs`) such as `/run` and put your files inside. They will then live within the virtual memory (and won't usually need any disk I/O). Of course the space they take are consuming virtual memory resources (so are limited).

BTW, on many Linux systems, writing small files don't use a lot of disk I/O because they sit in the file system cache.

Of course, any `tmpfs` file system loses all its content at every reboot, so you don't want to keep important unrecoverable data inside.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick has APIs for both C and PHP.  PHP IMagick appears to have montage hooks.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.montageimage.php

General info on PHP IMagick usage:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php